Layer::postDecStrong null pointer exception
My system is based on Android 11 AOSP. I've already implemented the following defensive checks in RenderState::postDecStrong, but during stress testing, I occasionally encounter the following null pointer error. How should I proceed with further defensive measures?
code：
void RenderState::postDecStrong(VirtualLightRefBase* object) {
    if (object == NULL) {
       return;
    }
    if (pthread_equal(mThreadId, pthread_self())) {
        object->decStrong(nullptr);
    } else {
//        mRenderThread.queue().post([object]() { object->decStrong(nullptr); });
        mRenderThread.queue().runSync([&]() { object->decStrong(nullptr); });
    }
}

tombstone：
pid: 968, tid: 3119, name: RenderThread  
uid: 1000
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x9
Cause: null pointer dereference
    r0  00000001  r1  00000001  r2  00000000  r3  00000000
    r4  b8c635b0  r5  ffbd88d0  r6  e92cb25c  r7  00000000
    r8  ac0a4e00  r9  00000001  r10 e903ba30  r11 ac0a4de0
    ip  ea43bd1c  sp  b5b120b0  lr  e832a513  pc  e832ecf8

backtrace:
      #00 pc 0015fcf8  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::Layer::postDecStrong()+2) (BuildId: 194a12a036e3025c31cc6d990c737e3f)
      #01 pc 0015b50f  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::DeferredLayerUpdater::destroyLayer()+34) (BuildId: 194a12a036e3025c31cc6d990c737e3f)
      #02 pc 0015bacf  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::DeferredLayerUpdater::detachSurfaceTexture()+12) (BuildId: 194a12a036e3025c31cc6d990c737e3f)
      #03 pc 0014d993  /system/lib/libhwui.so (std::__1::packaged_task<void ()>::operator()()+50) (BuildId: 194a12a036e3025c31cc6d990c737e3f)
      #04 pc 00140f6f  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::WorkQueue::process()+162) (BuildId: 194a12a036e3025c31cc6d990c737e3f)
      #05 pc 00158161  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+72) (BuildId: 194a12a036e3025c31cc6d990c737e3f)
      #06 pc 0000ee95  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+168) (BuildId: 54518163325fdfd1b9ec8d6c1c36ab2b)
      #07 pc 0000e9dd  /system/lib/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+256) (BuildId: 54518163325fdfd1b9ec8d6c1c36ab2b)
      #08 pc 000aab93  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+40) (BuildId: c958de26a3513759bb8936790e6b371b)
      #09 pc 00064003  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+30) (BuildId: c958de26a3513759bb8936790e6b371b)


Can you tell more about libhwui.so file ?
